# How to stop setInterval in loop

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

I trying to do equalizer animation. I did function for start animation, but i cant do function for stop animation, becouse clearInterval not working.

my codepen
https://codepen.io/naraxiss/pen/qyMamy

```js
var spans = document.querySelectorAll('span');
function getRandom() {
  return Math.random();
}
function scale(el){
  el.style.transform = 'scaleY(' + getRandom() +')';
}

var myInterval = null;

function startMusic (spans){
  var el = spans;
  for(var i = 0; i < el.length; i++){
      (function(i) {
            myInterval = setInterval(function(){
              scale(el[i]);
            }, 100);
      })(i);
    }  
}

function stopMusic (interval,els){
  
  clearInterval(interval);
  //console.log(els)
  
  for(var i = 0; i < els.length; i++){
    els[i].style.stransform = 'scaleY(0.05)'
     
    }
  
}



document.querySelector('.start').addEventListener('click', function(){
  startMusic(spans);
})

document.querySelector('.finish').addEventListener('click', function(){
  stopMusic(myInterval,spans);
})
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  
}

span{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-right: 10px;
  transition: 0.1s linear;
  transform: scaleY(0.005);
  transform-origin: bottom;
}

.equalizer{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="equalizer">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
<button class="start">START</button>
<button class="finish">FINISH</button>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use interval in a loop! I mean ever. Every loop starts a new interval, each repeats but you only stop one. Is that what you want? If you loop 10 times, you will have 10 intervals, each repeat its code every 100 milliseconds. Since you always overwrite the interval ID in the variable, you can only stop one interval.

Comment: ok
how i can loop animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save reference of each interval in an array like this

```
var myInterval = [];
function startMusic (spans){
  var el = spans;
  for(var i = 0; i < el.length; i++){
      (function(i) {
            let interval = setInterval(function(){
              scale(el[i]);
            }, 100);
            myInterval.push(interval);
      })(i);
    }  
}
```

and then in stopMusic function clear all of those intervals like this one.

```
function stopMusic (interval,els){

  interval.forEach(inter => clearInterval(inter));
  console.log(els)

  for(var i = 0; i < els.length; i++){
    els[i].style.stransform = 'scaleY(0.05)'

   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you create 5 intervals inside your for loop you need to stop them seperately.

```
var spans = document.querySelectorAll('span');

function getRandom() {
  return Math.random();
}

function scale(el) {
  el.style.transform = 'scaleY(' + getRandom() + ')';
}

var myInterval = []; // <------------------------ Make it an array

function startMusic(spans) {
  var el = spans;
  for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
      myInterval.push(setInterval(function() { // <------------- push every item 
        scale(el[i]);
      }, 100));
      console.log(myInterval)
    })(i);
  }
}

function stopMusic(els) {
  for (var x = 0; x < myInterval.length; x++) {
    clearInterval(myInterval[x]); // <--------------------- Access every item to clear
  }
  console.log(els)

  for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    els[i].style.stransform = 'scaleY(0.05)'

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work is because you start 5 intervals but only stop 1. Put the intervals in a array so you can loop them and stop them all. See change below.

```js
var spans = document.querySelectorAll('span');
function getRandom() {
  return Math.random();
}
function scale(el){
  el.style.transform = 'scaleY(' + getRandom() +')';
}

var myIntervals = [];

function startMusic (spans){
  var el = spans;
  for(var i = 0; i < el.length; i++){
      (function(i) {
            myIntervals[i] = setInterval(function(){
              scale(el[i]);
            }, 100);
      })(i);
    }  
}

function stopMusic (intervals,els){
  
  //clearInterval(interval);
  //console.log(els)
  
  for(var i = 0; i < els.length; i++){
    clearInterval(intervals[i]);
    els[i].style.stransform = 'scaleY(0.05)'
     
    }
  
}



document.querySelector('.start').addEventListener('click', function(){
  startMusic(spans);
})

document.querySelector('.finish').addEventListener('click', function(){
  stopMusic(myIntervals,spans);
})
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  
}

span{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-right: 10px;
  transition: 0.1s linear;
  transform: scaleY(0.005);
  transform-origin: bottom;
}

.equalizer{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="equalizer">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
<button class="start">START</button>
<button class="finish">FINISH</button>
```